# Messages are getting struck in apache activemq master-slave configuration

Tags: linux, apache, activemq-classic, messaging, messagebroker

I am facing problem of messages getting struck in activemq queue (with master slave configuration) and consumer is not able to consume messages when I pump around ~100 messages to different queues.

I have configured ActiveMQ (v5.9.0) message broker in two separate linux instances in master-slave mode. For persistenceAdapter conf on both the instances, I have mounted a NAS storage onto both the instances where activemq server is running. Hence same NAS storage is mounted on both activemq instances at mount point '/mnt/nas'. The size of the NAS storage is 20 GB.

So my persistenceAdapter conf looks like below

```
<persistenceAdapter>
      <kahaDB directory="/mnt/nas" ignoreMissingJournalfiles="true" checkForCorruptJournalFiles="true" checksumJournalFiles="true"/>
</persistenceAdapter>
```

The systemUsage configuration on both activemq server is like below

```
<systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap = "70"/>
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit = "15 gb"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit = "7 gb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
 </systemUsage>
```

and I have enabled only 'tcp' transport connector

```
<transportConnector name = "openwire" uri = "tcp://0.0.0.0:61616     maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

When I see the partition details of the mount point '/mnt/nas' on both activemq instances, I see following for the command df -k

```
Filesystem              1K-blocks        Used   Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda2              102953264     5840280    91883264   6% /
tmpfs                      967652           0      967652   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1                 253871       52511      188253  22% /boot
//nas151.service.softlayer.com/IBM278684-16
                      139328579072 56369051136 82959527936  41% /mnt/nas
```

Hence I see 41% of /mnt/nas is used

The problem is when I start the activemq server (on both instances), I see the following messages in the activemq.log

```
 **************** START ***************
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,350 | INFO  | PListStore:[/var/lib/apache-activemq-5.9.0/data/localhost/tmp_storage] started | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,454 | INFO  | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi | org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext | JMX connector
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,457 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/mnt/nas] | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,612 | INFO  | Corrupt journal records found in '/mnt/nas/db-1.log' between offsets: 8163..8209 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.Journal | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,613 | INFO  | Corrupt journal records found in '/mnt/nas/db-1.log' between offsets: 12256..12327 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.Journal | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,649 | INFO  | Corrupt journal records found in '/mnt/nas/db-1.log' between offsets: 20420..20585 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.Journal | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,650 | INFO  | Corrupt journal records found in '/mnt/nas/db-1.log' between offsets: 28559..28749 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.Journal | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,651 | INFO  | Corrupt journal records found in '/mnt/nas/db-1.log' between offsets: 32677..32842 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.Journal | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,652 | INFO  | Corrupt journal records found in '/mnt/nas/db-1.log' between offsets: 36770..36960 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.Journal | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,655 | INFO  | Corrupt journal records found in '/mnt/nas/db-1.log' between offsets: 49099..49264 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.Journal | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,657 | INFO  | Corrupt journal records found in '/mnt/nas/db-1.log' between offsets: 61403..61474 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.Journal | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,658 | INFO  | Corrupt journal records found in '/mnt/nas/db-1.log' between offsets: 65521..65567 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.Journal | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,659 | INFO  | Corrupt journal records found in '/mnt/nas/db-1.log' between offsets: 69614..69685 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.Journal | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:40,660 | INFO  | Corrupt journal records found in '/mnt/nas/db-1.log' between offsets: 77778..77824 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.disk.journal.Journal | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:41,543 | INFO  | KahaDB is version 5 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:41,592 | INFO  | Recovering from the journal ... | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:41,604 | INFO  | Recovery replayed 66 operations from the journal in 0.028 seconds. | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:41,772 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.0 (localhost, ID:10.106.99.101-60576-1401972521638-0:1) is starting | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:41,892 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: tcp://10.106.99.101:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:41,893 | INFO  | Connector openwire started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:41,893 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.0 (localhost, ID:10.106.99.101-60576-1401972521638-0:1) started | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:41,893 | INFO  | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:41,897 | WARN  | Store limit is 2048 mb, whilst the data directory: /mnt/nas only has 0 mb of usable space - resetting to maximum available disk space: 0 mb | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
 2014-06-05 12:48:41,897 | ERROR | Store limit is 0 mb, whilst the max journal file size for the store is: 32 mb, the store will not accept any data when used. | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
 ******************** END **************
```

I see 'Corrupt journal records found in '/mnt/nas/db-1.log'. This comes for everytime restart even though if I delete this file and restart.
I had put the flag to recover but still this log entry comes for every restart.

Another problem is, even though my NAS storage is 20GB, it shows '/mnt/nas only has 0 mb of usable space'. This is really weird. I am not sure why 0 MB is available to activemq

I request people here to give me some suggestions on why it is happening like this and suggest me any better configurations to avoid messages getting struck in queue.

Thanks

Raagu

Comment: I just debugged the source code of Apache ActiveMQ and found that when it tries to get usable space (using java.io.File.getUsableSpace() method) on the mount point /mnt/nas, it gets 0. Not sure why mount point returns 0

Comment: I would upgrade the ActiveMq to a more recent version. There was also a bug in 5.9.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4832 about storage space that is fixed in 5.9.1.